# Would this memory work on a MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

Can anybody tell me if this module: [Transcend 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L Unbuffered Non-ECC CL11 204-pin SO-DIMM](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Transcend-TS1GSK64W6H-1600MHz-Unbuffered-Non-ECC/dp/B008JIVN3I/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1452078454&sr=1-1&keywords=TS1GSK64W6H) would work on my MBP?

My memory specifications currently: 10 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 (1x8GB) + (1x2GB)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the 1600 MHz memory would work in that machine, but you can get an 8 GB upgrade that's guaranteed to work in your Mac [for less than the product you linked to](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/macbook-pro-%2817-inch%2C-early-2011%29) (click 'View more compatible memory upgrades' to see the single 8 GB module).

Answer (score 1):

No, your MacBookPro8,3 requires **1333 MHz** DDR3 SO-DIMM. The module above states **1600MHz** which is not correct.

This memory Kit should work in your MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011):
[2x 8 GB 204 Pin DDR3-1333 SO-DIMM (1333Mhz, PC3-10600S, CL9)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/204-DDR3-1333-SO-DIMM-1333Mhz-PC3-10600S/dp/B004Z1BSIS/ref=sr_1_10?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1452099437&sr=1-10&keywords=204-pin%20PC-10600%201333%20MHz%20DDR3%20SO-DIMM%2016GB)

[image]

Comment: Will it not downstep the speed of the module?

Comment: 2x 8GB memory would speed up your MacBook.

Comment: Yep. I already have an 8GB and a 2GB, so I want to replace the 2GB module with an 8GB.